# windows machine gets assigned wrong netmask

Tags: windows, dhcp, isc-dhcp

I have a Debian based DHCP server. It assigns correct netmask `225.225.225.0` for all devices (WiFi router, voip, scanner) except for the windows machines. They all get assigned `224.0.0.0` for some reason. They are all set to receive IP over DHCP; no manipulations with routing tables was done. Why do they get configured this way?

Settings of the `isc-dhcp-server`:

```
option domain-name "example.com";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ddns-update-style none;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option subnet-mask    225.225.225.0;
  range 192.168.1.20 192.168.1.200;
}

host gnulinuxpc {
  hardware ethernet 00:30:48:b8:52:cb;
  fixed-address 192.168.1.2;
  option subnet-mask    225.225.225.0;
}

host windowspc {
  hardware ethernet 00:18:f3:5e:bb:d3;
  fixed-address 192.168.1.3;
  option subnet-mask    225.225.225.0;
}
```

Comment: `option subnet-mask    225.225.225.0;` Not a valid mask

Comment: Do Windows clients get correct IP addresses? I mean, it's just the netmask what clients get an incorrect one..

Comment: @GregAskew wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: GregAskew - seeing as how you answered this, why not put this as a proper answer... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably a typo: `option subnet-mask 225.225.225.0;` Not a valid mask :-)